# Can int pointer be casted to char *?

Tags: c, pointers, alignment

The below program tests for Little/Big endian on intel processor. Actually little endian is correct output. First I am casting `int` to `char*` and accessing its value without initialization to `int *`.I am not understanding second part of output. Here `int` pointer is casted to `char *`. So why is not `int` pointer not changed its alignment to `char *`?

```
00000000 00000000 00000011 01111111 = 895
0        0         3       127

int main() {
    int num = 895;
    if(*(char *)&num == 127)
    {
        printf("\nLittle-Endian\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Big-Endian\n");
    }

    int *p = (char *)&num ;
    if(*p == 127)
    {
        printf("\nLittle-Endian\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Big-Endian\n");
    }
    printf("%d\n",*p);
}

o/p

Little-Endian
Big-Endian
895
```

Comment: What do you think cast does?

Comment: Formatting your code better will help people understand what's going on.

Comment: The return type of `main` shall be `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The  first half of your program using this comparison:

   ```
   if(*(char *)&num == 127)
   ```

   looks fine.
2. The second half of your program contains this assignment:

   ```
   int *p = (char *)&num ;
   ```

   Which isn't valid code.  You can't convert pointer types without an explicit cast.  In this case, your compiler might be letting you get away with it, but strictly speaking, it's incorrect.  This line should read:

   ```
   int *p = (int *)(char *)&num;
   ```

   or simply this equivalent statement:

   ```
   int *p = &num;
   ```

   From this example, I'm sure you can see why your second test doesn't work the way you'd like it to - you're still operating on the whole `int`, not on the single byte you were interested in.  If you made `p` a `char *`, it would work the way you expected:

   ```
   char *p = (char *)&num;
   ```

Comment: +1. Worth a mention that perhaps @Goutham intended to write `char *p = (char *)&num` in the second case?

Comment: @s.bandara, that might be what's going on.  But I don't understand why he'd do that when that is semantically identical to the first half of the program.  Maybe if he was just trying to do it two ways?

Comment: *"You can't convert pointer types without an explicit cast."* - To be pedantic, you pointers to `void` can be safely and implicitly converted to any pointer type.

Comment: @Ed, true, but that's an exception, and not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

> Can int pointer be cast to `char *`?

Yes, it's only the inverse that would invoke undefined behavior, more precisely, using the result of a cast from `char *` to `int *` (since `char` is 1-byte aligned, so any data pointer type can safely be cast to `char *`).

Comment: Casting `char*` to `int*` doesn't invoke UB. _Using_ the result of that cast _may_ invoke UB.